# Access sharepoint\office 365 using CSOM and grant_type=client_credentials

Tags: sharepoint, azure-active-directory, office365, csom

I have followed the instructions in this example:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/using-csom-for-dotnet-standard
And can connect fine :-) using grant_type=password, username and password

However i want to connect using client id and client secret...
[I have set these up in AzureAD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsWbI.png)

[i have added the permissions:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ln1Of.png)

[i have exposed the api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0H0x.png)

[this is the body of my request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtSov.png)

[at this point in the code i actually receive the token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3SCb.png)

[but here it fails with a 401](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lgEl.png)

i wonder if someone has an example of this working?

I have also tried this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azureacs
and i can get it working, whoever according to the documentation this has been retired on November 7, 2018.

I not sure what auth method it uses or how to identify the auth method.

Answer (score 0):

If this registration is only used for SharePoint, you do not need to expose an API.

You don't need scope. You will need to pass in the 'client_id' and 'resource' like below and it will look something similar to this for getting a token to make a call to SharePoint:

```
client_id: [appRegistrationClientId]@[tenantid]
Resource: 00000003-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000/[tenant].sharepoint.com@[tenant-id]
```

[image]

This will help too: https://anexinet.com/blog/getting-an-access-token-for-sharepoint-online/

Comment: Hi Brian i appreciate the info, yes that example works, however we were also hoping to use, if required, openid, 
ms graph
federation
ws-federation
saml-p

Comment: Hi Brian i appreciate the info, yes that example works, however we were also hoping to use, if required, openid, ms graph, federation, ws-federation, saml-p as these are listed in the Azure AD with simple configuration changes.
It seems strange that we can also connect with "grant_type=password" and not "grant_type=client_credentials" as per the example doc linked in line 1 of my question??